# I want the content on a website to be accessed by only selected ip addresses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser, ip

I want the content on a website to be accessed by only selected ip addresses.
but the dynamic ip keeps changing depending upon the source of internet access.
So is there any way by which i can Know the static ip of the computer and not the dynamic one assigned by the ISP from the browser.

Comment: better off using user authentication and not serve content if not authenticated and logged in

Comment: Do you mean [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)?

Comment: Yes is there any way to determine the mac address using something like jquery or from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.noip.com

This used to fix the dynamic IP problem when I was working as sysadmin, I am sure it will solve your problem.

There is no "static" ip, there is no other IP different from the one assigned by the ISP. There is also no way to get the mac address using javascript without anything else installed, since that information isn't part of the http protocol.

I can't see any easy way to achieve what you are trying to do without a vpn software.